# rss display android

Tags: android, rss

Hy, I'm trying to display my rss feed but the problem is that while trying to display the title the rss feed somehow displays everything (the link, title and even the name of the page I'm trying to read the feed from).
Here's a sample of the code.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
        }


        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setText(aaa);


    }




    public static List<JSONObject> getLatestRssFeed(){

        String feed = "http://www.net.hr/rss/feeds/naslovnica/index.xml";

    RSSHandler rh = new RSSHandler();
    List<Article> articles = rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
    Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Number of articles " + articles.size());
    return fillData(articles);

    }



    private static List<JSONObject> fillData(List<Article> articles) {

        List<JSONObject> items = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (Article article : articles) {
            JSONObject current = new JSONObject();
            try {
             buildJsonObject(article, current);

                 aaa=article.getTitle();
         /*
This is where I'm trying to get the title from actually
*/        
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error creating JSON Object from RSS feed");
        }
        items.add(current);
            }

            return items;
        }



        private static void buildJsonObject(Article article, JSONObject current) throws JSONException {
    String title = article.getTitle();

    }
```

There's also this class

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private Article currentArticle = new Article();
private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

private int articlesAdded = 0;

private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 1;

StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();


public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
chars = new StringBuffer();
}



public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
{
Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article title: " + chars.toString());
currentArticle.setTitle(chars.toString());

}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
{
Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article description: " + chars.toString());
currentArticle.setDescription(chars.toString());
}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
{
Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article published date: " + chars.toString());
currentArticle.setPubDate(chars.toString());
}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("encoded"))
{
Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article content: " + chars.toString());
currentArticle.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
{

}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
{
try {
Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article link url: " + chars.toString());
currentArticle.setUrl(new URL(chars.toString()));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
Log.e("RSA Error", e.getMessage());
}

}





if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

articleList.add(currentArticle);

currentArticle = new Article();


articlesAdded++;
if (articlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT)
{
throw new SAXException();
}
}
}





public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}



public List<Article> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
URL url = null;
try {

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

url = new URL(feedUrl);

xr.setContentHandler(this);
xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("RSS Handler IO", e.getMessage() + " >> " + e.toString());
} catch (SAXException e) {
Log.e("RSS Handler SAX", e.toString());
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
Log.e("RSS Handler Parser Config", e.toString());
}

return articleList;
}

}
```

Also just to note that since this is the first time I've encountered rss while programming this is not my code but here's the link
https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidRssReader/blob/master/src/com/tmm/android/rssreader/RssListAdapter.java
so I was wondering if there is some other problem (like different rss version or something) but I think not cause even his link did the same to my app.

Anyway I need the app to get only the headline of the 12 most recent news and the link to the news.
Thanks

Comment: the code that you've posted is not in the java file that you linked too...The link goes to an Adapter, and the code you've posted is an Activity and an RSSHandler.